# Creating a mongoose Schema using a javascript object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This might seem like a really silly question, but is it possible to pass a js object instead of having to write the key value pairs during a Schema assignment?

So, instead of `let schema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String})`, can you say

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose')

let obj = {name: String}
let schema = new mongoose.Schema(obj)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try that way and got any error?

Comment: It is possible. If you got any error while doing that, mention it.

Comment: The Schema structure seem slightly different in the two cases. I am not sure if the differences actually affect the database though, which is my primary concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the `key: type` pairs, validations etc in them as an object in the `Schema`. Basically, what it does, it passes the definition provided in the object to the schema constructor.

```
 constructor(definition?: SchemaDefinition, options?: SchemaOptions);
```

But whenever you write as an `object` way, autocomplete and other types won't be available (IDE intellisense) and causes more error-prone code when you compile it and also there is no effect on the database by doing this way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You can't.

Because that's how Mongoose works. That's a framework with many rules that we have to obey in order to successfully leverage its functionalities.